# How can I grab the callback reference from a bound callback in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, bind

I have the following problem : I need to move a widget from one container to another. I've mostly achieved it by copying the widget, with everything contained in that widget and deleting the original widget.

The only problem left to solve is the case of bound callbacks to the original widget, which I cannot rebind to the new widget unless I can get a reference to the callback function.

For instance :

```py
import tkinter as tk


def callback(ev):
    print('entered')

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.bind('<Enter>', callback)
print(frame.bind())  # ('<Enter>', )
print(frame.bind('<Enter>')  # 'if {"[64351688callback %# %b %f %h %k %s %t %w %x %y %A %E %K %N %W %T %X %Y %D]" == "break"} break\n'
```

Since `widget.bind(key)` doesn't return a reference to the callback function, how else can I grab that reference without having to hook directly into the `bind` method ?

Comment: If you don't need the original widget any more, why copy it?  Just `.pack()`/`.grid()` it into its new location.  No need to recreate the bindings.

Comment: Changing the parent of a widget is not trivial. The problem is not the layout, it's just that I want to change the widget's parent, i.e. moving a widget from the root widget to a new toplevel, or move a widget between frames in a ttk::Notebook widget, not just changing the widget's position inside the window.

Comment: @Dogeek: Pick one from [`[python][tkinter] unbind`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+unbind)

Comment: If you can conceivably structure things as moving a `frame` (and its contents, and no, not a `ttk::frame`, but you can put one of those directly inside to get the look) to become an independent toplevel, then you can use `wm manage` to convert the frame to a toplevel. I don't know exactly how to convert that into tkinter syntax; this is in Tcl/Tk form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `print( tk.__file__ )` you can get path to source code and see how it works.

In source code I found than you can use this string as callback

```
'if {"[64351688callback %# %b %f %h %k %s %t %w %x %y %A %E %K %N %W %T %X %Y %D]" == "break"} break\n'
```

So you can do

```
other_frame.bind('<Enter>', frame.bind('<Enter>'))
```